# Замаппить объекты в Java JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Имеется следующая структура БД PostgreSQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE a_type (
      id INT4 PRIMARY KEY
    );

    CREATE TABLE a (
      id        INT8 PRIMARY KEY,
      a_type_id INT4 NOT NULL REFERENCES a_type (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE b_type (
      id INT4 PRIMARY KEY
    );

    CREATE TABLE b (
      id        INT8 PRIMARY KEY,
      b_type_id INT4 NOT NULL REFERENCES b_type (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE c (
      id INT8 PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES a_type (id) REFERENCES b_type (id)
    );
```

Хотелось бы замаппить на доменные объекты в Java:

```
    @Entity
    interface A {
        @Id
        Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn
        AType aType;
    }

    @Entity
    class AType {
        @Id
        Integer id;
    }

    @Entity
    interface B {
        @Id
        Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn
        BType bType;
    }

    @Entity
    class BType {
        @Id
        Integer id;
    }

    @Entity
    class C implements A, B {
        @Id
        Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn
        AType aType;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn
        BType bType;
    }
```

Чтобы в Spring CRUD Repository можно было создать и использовать следующие репозитории:

```
    interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {
    }

    interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {
    }

    interface CRepository extends CrudRepository<C, Long> {
    }
```

То есть если существует в БД строка в таблице `c`, то с таким же ID существуют объекты в таблицах `a` и `b`.

Прошу подсказать в какую сторону смотреть, чтобы разобраться с тем какие аннотации JPA использовать для реализации задуманного.

Comment: Похвальное желание. Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Почему вы мапите поля в интерфейсах ? Они же будут статическими.